# Не отображается размер файла

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста! Моя функция не отображает размер файла, что я не правильно здесь накрутил.

Выводится на экран "Размер последнего загруженного файла: "

```
    function filesize_get() {
        $path = 'storage';
        $dira = scandir($path);
        $result = (count($dira))-1;
        $file = $dira[$result]; 
        echo $file;
        if(file_exists($file)){
            echo "Файл  отсутствует.";
            return "Файл  отсутствует."; // проверяем существует ли файл 
        }
        $filesizeR = filesize($file); //определяем размер файла 
        echo "Размер последнего загруженного файла: ".$filesizeR;
     }
```

Comment: Ну хотя бы даже `file_exists($file)` должно быть **!**`file_exists($file)` русскими словами конструкция переводится как - если файл **не** существует! А ваша конструкция переводится как - если файл существует. И при этом вы выводите инфу о том что - Файл  отсутствует! Я думаю суть ясна!

Comment: Погуглите на предмет знака **!** и его использование в php.

Comment: ниче не понял :) Ыыы, напишите плиз как должно быть

Comment: ааа все понял :)

Comment: Да, @BETEP, из серии *хотели, как лучше, а получилось как всегда...*. 

А если серьезно, то Вы проверяете не удалил ли кто-то файл за время между scandir() и filesize() ? 

С тем же успехом файл может быть удален и за время между file_exists() и filesize().

**А вот результат вызова scandir() проверять надо**.

Comment: Спасибо всем :)!

Comment: В общем сделал так:

function filesize_get() {

 $path = 'storage';
    $dira = scandir($path);
 $result = (count($dira))-1;
 $file = $dira[$result];

 if(!file_exists("storage/$file")){
  echo "Файл  отсутствует.";
  return "Файл  отсутствует."; // проверяем существует ли файл 
 }
 
 $filesize = filesize("storage/$file");
}

Comment: Всем по плюсу :) Спасибо

А может еще подскажете как вот это сделать: http://hashcode.ru/questions/97760/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: @BETEP, **а Вы уверены**, что последний (видимо Вы имеете в виду **по времени**), загруженный файл будет последним в массиве, возвращаемым scandir() ?

Разве она сортирует файлы по времени модификации ???

Answer (score 1):

Ну во-первых исправьте ошибку в условии, на которую вам указали в комментариях.
Во-вторых, можно использовать функцию [stat()](http://www.php.su/functions/?stat), для получения данных о файле, в том числе и его размера:

```
array stat ( string filename )
```

Она возвращает ассоциативный массив c данными о файле. Для получения размера файла, сделайте так (ниже приведен псевдокод):

```
$file_attributes = stat(filename);
echo $file_attributes[7];        // размер в байтах
echo $file_attributes["size"];   // то же самое
```

Answer (score 0):

Хотя бы так должно быть:

```
$path='gt/';
$files=scandir($path);
$lasttime=0;
$lastfile=false;
foreach($files as $k=>$v){
    if (file_exists($path.$v) &&  filemtime($path.$v)>$lasttime) {
        $lastfile=$path.$v;
        $lasttime=filemtime($lastfile);
    };
};
if ($lastfile) echo filesize($lastfile);
```